# ListView on RelativeLayout with Layout's OnTouchListener

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

In XML Code
I have a `RelativeLayout` and in that i am having a ListView.
i am using Layouts `OnClickListener`.

```
RLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//which will set an touch event for entire screen.
}
```

Now the problem is my list is as follows

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="236dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:choiceMode="none"
    android:focusable="false"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" >
</ListView>
```

and now only half of my screen i.e. part other than `ListView` is Responding to `OnTouchListener` Event.

Comment: you are missing `android:layout_height` attributes in `ListView`

Comment: no that's not a problem though.. while copy-pasting the code one of the snippet got mistakenly deleted by me. its there in the original code.

Comment: try setting your listview height to "fill_parent"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a temporary solution for my problem.
i used a New View as Overlay which will hide everything under it..

```
       <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

just before closing tag of RelativeLayout
and in java

`View view;
view = (View) findViewById(R.id.view);
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()`

works fine for me now.

Answer (score 1):

Override the touchevent for your RelativeLayout and try dispatching the touch event to the list too. Something like:

```
findViewById(R.id.list).dispatchTouchEvent(event);
```